# Could we boot Windows 10 on PCIe nvme expansion card (without messing with virtualization) on pre-Haswell?

Tags: windows, windows-10, nvme, ivy-bridge

Can we make very very old system (supposed Nahelem) boot from nvme expansion card?

Comment: Older Intel chipsets do not support booting from NVMe devices.  Nahelem is indeed one of those chipsets.

Answer (score 1):

There are methods said to be able to use NVMe on older legacy computers.
Personally, I have no experience with any of them, and for me they have the potential
for bricking the computer.

Without recommending any article, and taking no responsibility, here are
some resources:

- [NVMe BOOT via Clover](https://www.win-raid.com/t2375f50-Guide-NVMe-boot-without-modding-your-UEFI-BIOS-Clover-EFI-bootloader-method.html)
- [NVMe-boot for systems with legacy BIOS and older-UEFI (DUET-REFIND)](https://www.win-raid.com/t3286f50-Guide-NVMe-boot-for-systems-with-legacy-BIOS-and-older-UEFI-DUET-REFIND.html)
- [[Guide] How to get full NVMe support for all Systems with an AMI UEFI BIOS](https://www.win-raid.com/t871f50-Guide-How-to-get-full-NVMe-support-for-all-Systems-with-an-AMI-UEFI-BIOS.html)

Comment: The clover thing seems safe enough and promising. Brilliant, thank you very much.

Comment: If my answer has helped with the problem, please accept it.